# Create temporary PHP table from MySQL and SUM the values into another column

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with somes values. I want to create a temp table and insert into a new column like balance, the cumulative sum of the values. Then I want to get the id of the value with the lowest balance value.
Thus far I have put together this code:

```
$query_temp = "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS add_balance SELECT valor FROM movimentos";
$result_temp = mysqli_query($conn, $query_temp);

$response_temp = array();
while($row_temp= mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_temp)) {
    $response_temp = $row_temp;
}

$query = "SELECT _id FROM add_balance WHERE MIN(saldo)";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
```

I guess I would need a loop to insert into the new column 'balance', the sum of the row with the cumulative sum that far. This is what I think it would work, but I don't' know how to do this loop or if there's another way to do this.
Help appreciated.

Comment: Your question is not clear, you need to show examples of you table and data and an example of your wanted result.... that would help a lot.

Comment: There is no need of a temporary table to do that
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem